# Emacs on Windows: mapping the Meta key to something else than Alt

Tags: windows, emacs, meta

I read for a few hours on different threads for this issue without any results. Every time I was doing searches for something like

> "lwindow" meta

I was always getting into EmacsWin32 code which appears to be code developed in 2006.

So, here I am to ask the question:

Is it possible to remap the **Meta key**, for Emacs, in **Windows** to something else than <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

I would prefer to remap it to the Windows key, but I don't think it is possible. Then the <kbd>Fn</kbd> (function) key would be a good alternative.

I need my <kbd>Alt</kbd> key operational in Emacs since it is used for all kind of things on a French keyboard.

Comment: The Esc key is already Meta. M-C-x can be typed as esc, ctrl-x

Comment: @tripleee ok, will test that (but not sure it is as convenient than having the Windows or Fn keys, but maybe :) ) In any case, the real thing I want to do here is to have the Alt key working normally (not having it bound to Meta)

Comment: Your best bet may be to investigate Autohotkey and its scripting capabilities. You can remap Win key to Alt (which emacs can continue to interpret as meta) just for emacs frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the only thing that worked for me is to use the

```
(require 'iso-transl)
```

That is making sure that the mapping of my (Canadian) French keyboard is working properly.

Then I started to use the **right** <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of the left one. That way, I can do everything that I was doing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: `iso-transl` is a very old package that uses deprecated methods to input accented chars (and limited to latin-1).  If you find you need this package, it's likely just working around a bug elsewhere, so you should `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Windows, but `w32-pass-alt-to-system`, `w32-alt-is-meta`, `w32-lwindow-modifier`, and `w32-rwindow-modifier` seem like good candidates (maybe combined with `w32-pass-lwindow-to-system` and friends).